# If a value in one field is x then make a value in another field y using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, macros

I currently have a spreadsheet that has a number of borrowers. I wish for if the number of borrowers in column V is more than 1 for it to return a value of NA in column HD and if it is just one borrower for it to return a value of ND.

I currently have the following but could somebody please advise how I get this to start from the fifth row down and if there is a faster way as there are tens of thousands of fields and it is doing each one manually.

Sub Change()

Dim lngLoop As Long

lngLoop = 1

For lngLoop = 1 To Rows.Count

If Cells(lngLoop, 22).Value = "1" Then Cells(lngLoop, 212).Value = "NA"

If Cells(lngLoop, 22).Value > 1 Then Cells(lngLoop, 212).Value = "ND"

Next lngLoop
End Sub

Comment: I think you've answered your own question "a simple if statement" I doubt you'll get anyone to write it for you.

Comment: Start by showing what you tried. People are more inclined to help you correct your mistakes, than do your (simple) job for you. It's actually how stackoverflow works.

Comment: You don't even need VBA for this...a simple `Formula` will do

Comment: It is automated data that is already part of a bigger macro, having a formula would not work as the amount of cells changes on a monthly basis.

Comment: Range("HD5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-190]>1,""ND"",""NA"")"
    Range("HD5").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.FillDown

Comment: u don need vba or formula to do this. a simple find and replace will do. first find all '1' and replace with NA, then find all numbers and replace with ND

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I noticed a few things wrong with your code.

First your first "If" statement treats the value as a string because you have string value of "1" and not the integer value 1 that is being tested.

Second, if you have thousands of rows that you are processing and reading/writing to you should always turn off `ScreenUpdating`.

Finally, to make your code more efficient use the range objects instead of `Cells(x,y)`.

Give this a try and let me know if it works for you:

```
Sub Change()
Dim workingRange As Range
Dim workingCell As Range

'This will make your code run much faster. Make sure to turn it back on at the end as I did.
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Sets the range up. (Assumes you have no data below the 1millionth row)
Set workingRange = Range("V5:V" & Range("V1000000").End(xlUp).Row)

'Loops through all the cells in Column V that have data
For Each workingCell In workingRange.Cells
    If workingCell.Value = 1 Then Cells(workingCell.Row, 212).Value = "NA"
    If workingCell.Value > 1 Then Cells(workingCell.Row, 212).Value = "ND"
Next workingCell



'Turns Screen Updating back on
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'Clean up
Set workingRange = Nothing
Set workingCell = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I am getting an error with workingrange as nothing, apologies if I am being stupid here, is there something I should be doing differently to what you have posted above.

P.s. thank you for your help with this

Comment: Sorry my bad, I just noticed two bugs with my code. I fixed them now. Just copy paste it and try again.